# Printing a list into blocks of letters - Python

Tags: python, list

Still new to Python so my apologies..
I'm trying to print out a list into blocks of letters. Specifically 7, but I'm not sure how to remove the commas and lines.

[What I currently have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcOeq.png)

```
for index in range(0, len(populatedList), 7) :
print (populatedList[index:index+7])
```

[What I'm trying to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzFrX.png)

Comment: Please edit your question and put the data from the pictures in code blocks.

Comment: Can you be a little more clear about your inputs and outputs? The pictures you gave don't really match each other.

Comment: what is the rule/criteria to form a block of letters?

Comment: Please post text and not images.  That said, you can use `print(''.join(your_list_here))` to print your list items joined by empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following should work:

```
for index in range(0, len(populatedList), 7) :
  print ("".join(populatedList[index:index+7]))
```